# Why is ActiveRecord creating different ruby object when querying the same record?

Tags: unit-testing, activerecord, rspec

I'm trying to test a named scope in my Rails model with RSpec using FactoryBot.  I'm creating several records, where only one is returned by the scope.

```rb
RSpec.describe GemNamespace::GemModel, type: :model do

  before(:all)
    FactoryBot.create(:gem_model, :trait1)  # id 1
    FactoryBot.create(:gem_model, :trait2)  # id 2
    FactoryBot.create(:gem_model, :trait3)  # id 3
  end

  let(:included_record) { GemNamespace::GemModel.find 1 }

  describe 'my_named_scope' do
    it 'returns only records matching the conditions' do
      scope_results = GemNamespace::GemModel.my_named_scope
      expect(scope_results).to contain_exactly(included_record)
    end
  end

end
```

The test is failing because even though `included_record` is the only record in the `scope_results`, some debugging shows that the `included_record` is actually a different Ruby object than the one in the results for some reason.  Thus, the **contain_exactly** fails.

I've done scope testing like this on tons of models and it's always worked.  The only difference with this one is that the model is defined inside a gem, and I'm extending its functionality by adding my named scope to it in my Rails app.

What am I missing?  Why is it behaving like this only for this model?

If it matters:

> - Ruby 2.5.0
> - Rails 5.1.5
> - rspec 3.7.0
> - rspec-rails 3.7.2
> - factory_bot(_rails) 4.8.2

---

**UPDATE:**  I'll put this here instead of editing the above.  I am actually testing a database view as opposed to a table.  The views do not have a unique id column, so I'm not actually doing a `GemNamespace::GemModel.find 1` above, but instead a `where(column: <condition value>)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with a workaround.  I don't know too much about the internals of Rails, but it seems that the database view (and corresponding model) not having an `id` column kinda screws things up (i.e., the separate Ruby objects being created).  So I simply compared all the values of the two objects "manually"

```rb
# As a workaround, we're just gonna convert them both to Ruby hashes using
# the #as_json method, and compare those instead.

expect(scope_results.as_json).to contain_exactly(included_record.as_json)
```